# Keeping Tally of Characters in Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, file, variable-assignment, caesar-cipher

I'm working on a Caesar Cipher program for an assignment and I have the general understanding planned out, but my function for determining the decipher key is unnecessarily long and messy.

```
while(inFile().peek != EOF){
      inFile.get(character);
      if (character = 'a'|| 'A')
         { aCount++; }
      else if (character = 'b' || 'B')
         { bCount++; }
```

so on and so on.

What way, if it's possible, can I turn this into an array?

Comment: we do like assisting people and this is not do the work for me this is how do i improve something existing

Comment: character = 'a' || 'A' is wrong on two levels.

1. = is the assignment operator, while == is the comparison operator


2. 'a' || 'A'' doesn't mean if it is equal to 'a' or equal to 'A', you have to do if (character == 'a' || character == 'A')

Comment: In C++, characters are really just short ints and they are sequential.  You could use that property as an offset (hint: `index = tolower(character) - 'a'`)

Comment: Are you asking how to read text into an array?

Comment: Firstly, you are using assignment operator in comparison where you don't need to use it now. And about your question: I suggest you to use regular expressions which are defined in regex header. They are much elegant than the messy wall of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
int count [26] = {0};
while(inFile().peek != EOF){
  inFile.get(character);
  if (int (character) >=65 || int (character) <=90)
     { count [(int (character)) - 65] ++; }
  else if (int (character) >=97 || int (character) <=122)
     { count [(int (character)) - 97] ++; }
}
```

P.S. This is checking for the ASCII value of each character and then increment its respective element in the array of all characters, having 0 index for A/a and 1 for B/b and so on.
Hope this helps...

---

P.S. - There was an error in your code, `=` is an assignment operator and `==` is a conditional operator and you do not assign value in `if` statement, you check for condition... **So always use `==` to check for equality**...

Comment: I think you should initialize your count array to 0, else you might get random values

Comment: Consider using `while ( infile.get(character)) {... ` and `'a'` or `'z'` instead of plain numbers.

Comment: Its just one way of solving the problem, yeah your part is also right @Bob__ and I believe there can be other ways to solve the problem too... I user numbers so as to explain the concept of ASCII more clearly... :)

Comment: Maybe you should keep the char values and replace 65 with 'a', 97 with 'z' and so on. It would be easier to read, removes the need for the cast, and OP would probably understand it better.

Comment: We need to cast as there are capital A and small a and we need to treat them same, and the easy way I know is cast them... @pie3636

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array in the following manner

```
int letterCount['z'] = {0}; //z is the highest letter in the uppercase/lowercase alphabet


while(inFile().peek != EOF){

  inFile.get(character);
  if (character > 'A' && character < 'z')
  letterCount[character]++;

}
```

You can also use a hashmap like this

```
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<char,int> charMap;

while(inFile().peek != EOF){

  inFile.get(character);
  if (charMap.find(character) == charMap.end())
    charMap[character] = 1;
  else
    charMap[character] = charMap[character] + 1;

}
```

In case you do not know, a [hashmap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) functions as an array, where the index can be any class you like, as long as it implements a hash function.

Comment: You may want to add some [out of range](https://ideone.com/RkKIU0) checking before using `character` as an index...